# How to asynchronously download images in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I want to first create imageview onto the scroll view.there i set placeholder image or give Background color of imageview.so all image view are display.

```
- (void)LoadDataInScrollView
{
    dispatch_queue_t imageQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Image Queue",NULL);

    //totalImageGetDict into count total Number of object and generate imageview.

    for (int ivalue = 0; ivalue < [totalImageGetDict count]; ivalue++) 
    {
        dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{

            //define x value
            CGFloat xOrigin =ivalue *ascrollView.frame.size.width+50;

            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            imageView.tag = ivalue;
            [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin-40,imgYpos, ascrollView.frame.size.width-20, scrollViewHight);

            //then here first i set already downloaded image.it's comes from another class. getImageLoadDict into images are already downloaded**

            if ([getImageLoadDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:ivalue]]!= nil)   
            {
                //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [imageView setImage:[getImageLoadDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:ivalue]]];
                //});

            } 
            else 
            {
                //totalImageGetDict into remaining images object and asynchronously download here.

                STVisionPhoto *photoObj = [totalImageGetDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:ivalue]];
                UIImage *newimage = [photoObj image];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [imageView setImage:newimage];
                });
           }

           [ascrollView addSubview:imageView];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ASIHTTP or AFNetworking in your code? Just want to see if you are - then try and use there categories for downloading images asynchronously on the background thread.

Comment: @RenoJones, i m not used that class.i call using Nsurl class.

Comment: Ah okay. Then go for SDWebImage (they are handling async downloading in a better way) and you dont have to add headache on your soul for image downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to do it.It is pretty easy to use

Edit :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:your url]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imgview setImage:image];
    });
});
```

You can try this if you don't want to use any library

Comment: i do not wish to use any library.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of not (directly) using NSURLConnection.

Comment: +1 ur ans is right.i check it & accept it but it's not satisfied my condition.Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(12.5, 12.5, 80, 80);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 UIImage *profileImage;
 profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_URL_STRING]]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            imgView.image = profileImage;

                                          });


                             });

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: ,I trie this and also follow the Lazy loader class.

Comment: +1 ur ans is right.i check it & accept it but it's not satisfied my condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)loadImg:(NSString *)url img :(UIImageView *)imgView{
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
__weak UIImageView *imageV = imgView;
[imgView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songRecDef"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    imageV.image = image;
    [imageV setNeedsLayout];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    [imageV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songRecDef"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
}
```